# iPhone && Chipmunk- how to sync two shapes

Tags: iphone, physics, chipmunk

One of my sprite consists of two shapes. How can I sync two shapes, i.e, the shapes moves together, the distance, angle and etc between them keeps constant ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Chipmunk documentation](http://files.slembcke.net/chipmunk/release/ChipmunkLatest-Docs/#cpShape):

> You can add multiple shapes to a body. This should give you the flexibility to make any shape you want as well providing different areas of the same object with different friction, elasticity or callback values.

Comment: The problem is how can I sync the shape attached to the same body.

Comment: If you attach multiple shapes to the same body, they will move together automatically. Or what do you mean by "sync"?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by sync them? You define them relative to the body that they are attached to, Chipmunk syncs them for you automatically. You don't have to do anything, and you couldn't even if you wanted to for some reason. It doesn't even provide you the API to sync them manually if you wanted it.